# Unable to find sigtrap exception

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have submitted my app for review, but apple team regularly rejecting my app and telling they are getting exception. but i have tried it in multiple device and i am not getting any exception. they are telling they are getting exception while entering otp. i have given crash report provided by apple team below.

```
func validateOTP() -> Void {    


    var strOTP = String(format: "%@%@%@%@", txtFieldFirst.text ?? "1",txtFieldSecond.text ?? "0",txtFieldThird.text ?? "1",txtFieldFourth.text ?? "0")
    strOTP = strOTP.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
    print("OTP:",strOTP)
    if strOTP.count == 4 {

        if isServerReachable() {                

            var dict: [String : Any] = [:]
            dict["mobile"] = Defaults().strUserMobileNumber
            dict["otp"] = strOTP
            dict["device_id"] = StringConstant.Device.Id
            dict["registration_id"] = Defaults().strDeviceToken
            dict["device_type"] = StringConstant.Device.DeviceType

            SVProgressHUD.show()

            if strLoginType == StringConstant.kUserTypeStudent {

                CCAParserLayer.callStudentLogin(dict, handler: { strStatus, strMessage, dictResponse in
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    if (strStatus == "YES") {
                        let json = JSON(dictResponse!)
                        Defaults().strUserType = StringConstant.kUserTypeStudent
                        Defaults().strStudentId = json["student_data"][0]["student_id"].stringValue
                        Defaults().strUserId = json["student_data"][0]["user_id"].stringValue
                        Defaults().strStudentName = json["student_data"][0]["student_name"].stringValue
                        Defaults().strStudentMobile = json["student_data"][0]["student_mobile"].stringValue
                        Defaults().isLoggedIn = true
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "otpToStudentDashboard", sender: self)
                    }else{
                        self.showToastAlert(strMessage ?? StringConstant.kErrorMsg)
                    }
                })

            }else{

                CCAParserLayer.callCoachLogin(dict, handler: { strStatus, strMessage, dictResponse in
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    if (strStatus == "YES") {
                        let json = JSON(dictResponse!)
                        Defaults().strUserType = StringConstant.kUserTypeCoach
                        Defaults().strUserId = json["user_id"].stringValue
                        Defaults().isLoggedIn = true
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "otpToCoachDashboard", sender: self)
                    }else{
                        self.showToastAlert(strMessage ?? StringConstant.kErrorMsg)
                    }
                })

            }

        }else{
            showToastAlert(StringConstant.kNoInternet)
        }
    }
}
```

You can find crash report here : https://iosapps-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/Purple123/v4/c8/b4/f4/c8b4f459-268d-9e4f-41dc-e1a1debd59eb/attachment-14470021504513854757crashlog-F30F5C6F-07C9-4CC4-8B64-F59D82FB8BE3.txt?accessKey=1589094390_3573176945688459523_oOvkQoPlbl9fPoJG1v1vK5NdJTucUtWucC9bizZwY9B4EZuopjhvtKxf1naNx4BtYBPHmq2Ea0IfZs6uAOK65demdPuIBJvsxNIPFfrYYRhSRFT8ltCRFGBdHI5M8WWPyiCP4eRCwPkGaVVgFFVibbGEpYk4eDyInD0EiVNTfc8rDwSroUxEhY%2BdhrzluHhCVRkaPC5aMqSVFmY%2BMvW9SyvdvqS3dYOCEUb509YanCazpFPm%2FXSgxoTQFlNvzOnY

Comment: please share more description / detail.

Comment: @emrcftci i have submitted crash report and when they are getting exception. Please check.